# R: Change font size in plot_ly

Tags: r, plotly, font-size, r-plotly

I've been trying to change the size of the labels on my *x* and *y* axes of a graph drawn using *plot_ly* in R.

Below is my code:

```
q <- plot_ly(
    x=colnames(avg_exp_norm),
    y=row.names(avg_exp_norm),
    z = avg_exp_norm, type = "heatmap") %>% 
    layout(xaxis = list(size = 15), yaxis = list(size = 5))
q
```

But it doesn't work and in the result I don't see any changes in font size.

What I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify the font size inside a *nested* `list`.

Here is a minimal reproducible example

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(2017)
x <- seq(1:10)
y <- x + rnorm(10)
plot_ly(
    x = ~x,
    y = ~y + rnorm(10)) %>%
    layout(
        xaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 15)), 
        yaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 5)))
```

[image]

See [here](https://plot.ly/r/axes/) for more options on how to modify/theme your axes.

If you want to change *both* axes labels *and* titles, you can use e.g. `xaxis = list(titlefont = list(size = 5), tickfont = list(size = 5))`.