# Readable names on X-axis

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to plot Barchart with around 65 names on X-axis with Plotly. Below you can see the code

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)
df1<-structure(list(code = c("01", "02", "03", "10-12", 
                                              "13-15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
                                              "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31-32", "33", "35", "36", 
                                              "37-39", "45", "46", "47", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "58", 
                                              "59-60", "61", "62-63", "64", "65", "66", "68<U+0410>", "68B", 
                                              "69-70", "71", "72", "73", "74-75", "77", "78", "79", "80-82", 
                                              "84", "85", "86", "87-88", "90-92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "B", 
                                              "F", "I", "T"), rate = c(0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.25, 
                                                                                    0.18, 0.12, 0.11, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 
                                                                                    0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 
                                                                                    0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 
                                                                                    0.18, 0.13, 0.13, 0, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 
                                                                                    0.18, 0.18, 0.14, 0.15, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 
                                                                                    0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.15, 0.18)), row.names = c(NA, -64L), class = "data.frame")

df1<-data.frame(df1)

plt <- plot_ly(df1) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~code, y = ~rate, type = 'bar', name = 'Test') %>% 
    layout(
    xaxis = list(title = ''), 
    yaxis = list(title = ''),
    legend = list(x = 0.9, y = 0.99),
    barmode = 'group'
  )

plt
```

This code gives me Barchart, which is not fully readable on X-axis, and I can't see the full names of each name on the axis.
[image]

For example name `10-12` is not readable on the axis and so on.

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and to see all names on X-axis

Comment: Some options: 1) use smaller font 2) make your plot wider 3) offset the labels so every other one uses a different baseline 4) split your data into sections to plot separately 5) summarize the labels so all the bars of the same length get labeled with a list of all the applicable labels, e.g. 0.18 is "19, 20, 21, etc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this depends upon the two things.
First the canvas dimensions (size). You code is returning correct x axis if output is simly rescaled. Here is the screenshot.
[image]

The second. The font size. If the canvas size is OK adjust the font size of axis labels here:

```
plt <- plot_ly(df1) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~code, y = ~rate, type = 'bar', name = 'Test') %>% 
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = '',
                 tickfont = list(size = 5) # <<<<<< HERE
                 ), 
    yaxis = list(title = ''),
    legend = list(x = 0.9, y = 0.99),
    barmode = 'group'
  )
```

You can set it as big or small as you wish. You can also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51527864/5043424) answer. The proposed code correction is returning this (without rescaling of canvas):

[image]

I put the font size on second place as it should be adjusted after the canvas size is known and finally set to the necessary value.